# how to rotate an image in both directions in android

Tags: android, imageview, rotation

hi i need to rotate an ImageView in my app on touch

and i am using the following code

```
public android.view.View.OnTouchListener onTableTouched = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener(){
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {

WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(evt);

ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
// Dump touch event to log
dumpEvent(event);
//
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
mode = NONE;      
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if(mode == NONE){
updateRotation();
}
break;
}
return true;
}
};


private void updateRotation()
{

 matrix.postRotate(10);

 Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(itembmp, 0, 0,itembmp.getWidth(), itembmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 itembmp=redrawnBitmap;
 image.setImageBitmap(itembmp);
}
```

but by using this i can rotate the image in clock-direction only.

But i need to rotate the image in both directions .

How to do that.

Comment: What rotation logics do you want to apply? (In general you should give a negative value to your `postRotate()` func)

Comment: how to know through onTouchListener either it is clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation

Comment: So you want to know how to tell which rotation to apply? Or in other words, where was the screen touched?

Answer (score 0):

I would make two functions, one called updateRotationClockwise, one called updateRotationCounterClockWise.

In clockwise, it should stay:

```
 matrix.postRotate(10);
```

In counterclockwise, it should say:

```
matrix.postRotate(350);
```

Comment: how to know through onTouchListener either it is clockwise or counterclockwise rotation

Answer (score 0):

I am in process of developing this logic.
1. Difference in angle. one needs to also check other boundary conditions for more accuracy.
2. Instead of handling touch actions. I used  in build ScaleGestureDetector class for information.
In onScaleBegin assuming I get the event using a setter (called in on touch) in the OnScaleGestureListener.
before=gety/getx;
In on ScaleEnd
after=gety/getx;

thus difference is  tan-1(before)-tan-1(after)
if +tive anticlockwise -tive clockwise.
It is not so accurate I am adding conditions but one can try this out.

Answer (score 0):

from the class ClockView you can find the method for rotation for your bitmap image

https://github.com/jselbie/xkcdclock